# Positioning 3 Bootstrap Jumbotrons on a webpage

Tags: html, css

This is part of the code for my login webpage...

```
<div class="container-fluid align-content-center"   >

                    <div class="col-md-12">

*This is the 1st jumbotron for displaying the client logo*
                        <div class="jumbotron align-content-right col-4 float-right" style="background-color:White">
                      <div class="form-group align-content-center">
<%--                        <div style="float:none">--%>


                                                                          <asp:Image ID="imglogo" runat="server"  />
       <%--                 </div>--%>
                    </div>   
                        </div>

*This is the 2nd jumbotron for displaying the product logo and holds text fields for entering login credentials*
             <div class="jumbotron align-content-left col-5 " style="background-color:White; border: 5px; border-color:red">

                     <div class="form-group">

                                            <asp:Image ID="imgcubelogo" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/IMAGES/erp big.jpg" />
                    </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCompany" runat="server" Text="Company Name" class="form-control"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCompany" runat="server" class="form-control" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboCompany_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Financial Year" class="form-control"> </asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlfinalcialyear" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtUsername" runat="server" TextMode="singleline" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnlogin" runat="server" Text="Login" class="form-control" TabIndex="3" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" Font-Size="Medium" Style="margin-right: 30px;" TabIndex="4">Change Password</asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF8080" Text=":" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                    </div>


                        </div>

*This is the 3rd jumbotron for displaying the company logo*
                 <div class="jumbotron align-content-right col-4 float-right" style="background-color:White; border: 25px; border-color:red">
                                <div class="form-group align-content-right">

                                                                        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/IMAGES/eshabu.jpg" />       
                    </div>


                                               </div>
                    </div>
```

The current positions of these jumbotrons on the webpage are shown;
[This is the top half of the page where you can see jumbotrons 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEKE8.png) and [this is the bottom half of the page where you can see the 3rd jumbotron too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBaaU.png)

As you can see, the 3rd jumbotron appears only at the bottom of the page and can be seen only after scrolling down. I want it to appear just a little below the 1st jumbotron, along its same line. That way, I will able to see the contents of all 3 jumbotrons at once. I have been working on it for several days now; still haven't figured out a solution. Please help.

(I really don't have much experience in coding. I'm still learning.)

[Webpage after suggested edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T90So.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the float right property for the first jumbotron you need to add float left property on the second jumbotron. Because if you will not add float left to the second jumbotron it will take full width. And the third jumbotron will come after the first and second jumbotron.

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #000;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.one{
  float: right;
}
.two{
  float: left;
}
.three{
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  1
</div>
<div class="two">
  2
</div>
<div class="three">
  3
</div>
```

Comment: I did as you had suggested, and got the 3rd jumbotron to the desired position. But then now, the blue background, along with the "powered by.." statement has moved up to form a thin blue line. Its only because of the addition of the "float-left" to the second jumbotron, as when i tried removing it, it went back to the original state.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need any extra css for the layout you want. you can simply make it by bootstrap. implement it on your code and let me know if you need any help.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1 class="display-4">Jumbroton 2</h1>
      <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Jumbroton 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1 class="display-4">Jumbroton 3</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Powered by Echosoft</p>
</div>
```